# How do I choose the between two correct answers?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64951333/combine-these-into-a-single-var) that got two answers that both work perfectly and solve my problem. (In completely different ways)

What one should I mark as accepted? Is it possible to mark two as correct? I don't want to mark one as accepted so the other person is left without reward.

Comment: You don’t _have_ to mark any answer; if you can’t choose, don’t.

Comment: The accept mark doesn't mean it is *correct*. You mark an answer as accepted if that  answer helped you the most solving your question. In theory this could mean you "accept" an totally wrong answer as long as it helped you the best to solve your problem (*this answer is so wrong, I finally see where my problem is, thanks! Have an accept mark for that.*). In this case you probably picked one of the answers for the actual implementation, you could argue that answer helped you the most and is therefor a more likely candidate for your accept vote.

Comment: How about a coin toss?

Comment: upvote both and mark that, that you actually used

Comment: @nbk I think that's what I'm going to go for. Thanks for the help!